# How can i make a live query field in my android app that queries to my MYSQL database without the need to press search

Tags: android, mysql, search

I have a working search function that inserts search results into a spinner, but i want it to be live without the need to press a search button just like google. 
Something like this: [image]

Comment: Something along these lines? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, you need to use an AutoCompleteTextView, that triggers a filter each time that the text change, and show the suggestions exactly as the image that you attached.

Then, you must be your custom adapter and add it to your view in your onCreate function of your activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    AutomaticSearchAdapter adapter = new AutomaticSearchAdapter(this, new ArrayList<CustomObject>(), "");
    listView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.search_complete);
    listView.setThreshold(1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ...
}
```

Here is a template of how you can build your custom adapter, that load data from any API and suggest according to your own filtering criteria

```
public class AutomaticSearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements AsyncResponse, Filterable {
    private ArrayList<ContactItem> realList; // The list that will be shown
    private ArrayList<CustomObject> results =  new ArrayList<CustomObject> (); // A list with all data from your API

    private Filter mFilter = new Filter(){
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null) {
                String constraintTrim = ContactSearchAdapter.toPlain(constraint.toString()).trim().toLowerCase();


        // When te user introduces at least 3 characteres, get data from your API
                if (constraintTrim.length() == 3) {
            // Call Here to you API, and populate results
                }

        ArrayList<CustomObject> suggestions =  new ArrayList<CustomObject> ();
                for (CustomObject object : results) {
            if(/*some condition on your downloaded datum */) {
                suggestions.add(object);
            }
                }

                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
            }

            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
            if(results == null){
                return;
            }

            try {
                realList.clear();
                if (results.values != null){
                    realList.addAll((List<CustomObject>) results.values);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }catch ( Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };


    public int getCount() {
        return realList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        try {
            if (realList.size() > 0 ) {
                return realList.get(position);
            }else {
                return null;
            }
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // HERE MUST BE YOUR CUSTOM getView FROM YOUR LIST
        // YOU CAN LEARN MORE ABOUT http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void postStart() {
        //Nothing to do.
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }
}
```

Of course, you will need refactor the code above for your own requirements.

Comment: I will make a function that grabs my search results and puts them in a hidden ArrayList, then i will use the above code to make it search from the already parsed data to get my desired result. But wouldn't this be bad practice if the database size large.

Comment: Always that you make a get requesto to a API, you must to set a LIMIT, but it will interfer with a the results, because, the query would not be on the hidden ArrayList. So, the best thing to do in these case is make request of to the API until the results be greater that the LIMIT, and when the results are less than the LIMIT, you can stop doing web requests, and only filtering on your hidden ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

I bevieve what you need is an onTextChanged listener take a look here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html